# ColumnLayout with images occupying only the minimum space in QML

Tags: qt, listview, layout, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` with `ColumnLayout` delegates containing images that could be of any size. I want each delegate to occupy the least possible width and height they can, only defining a certain maximum width, but I can't get images to size right instead of being centered in a box (shown by the gray rectangles here):

[image: Current result]

My code is this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 800
    visible: true
    color: "black"

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 3

        delegate: ColumnLayout {
            width: listView.width

            Label {
                text:
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing " +
                    "Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa."
                color: "white"
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                font.pixelSize: 22

                Layout.maximumWidth: listView.width / 2
            }

            Image {
                asynchronous: true
                source: "https://picsum.photos/1024/256"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

                Layout.maximumWidth: listView.width / 2

                Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "#222"; z: -1 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the right behavior when using `Column` instead of `ColumnLayout` and replacing the `Layout.maximumWidth` lines by `width: Math.min(implicitWidth, listView.width / 2)`, as shown below, but I need to use layouts in my project:

[image: Wanted result]

Comment: What do you mean by "size right"? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Mitch There shouldn't be any blank space before and after the images.

Comment: OK, so you want the images to vertically fill their parent. You should update your question to be more specific, as it isn't so clear currently.

Answer (score 0):

The blank space before after image is because of  `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit`, it tries to keep the aspect ratio of image (i.e image width/ image height). You should use `fillmode: Stretch` to fill the space completely.

Comment: I need the images to fit. If I use a `Column` instead of `ColumnLayout`, I get the expected behavior, but then everything else becomes horribly complicated for interfaces with lots of element where I need minimum/preferred/maximum sizes.

Comment: you have set column layout width to be half of list view width. So you have blank space on right side.

Comment: @sana, you can't have a rectangular image both preserve it's aspect ratio and take up all blank space in its square parent unless you use e.g. Stretch or PreserveAspectCrop as the fillMode. You should post an image of the result you get when using Column (since you said that shows the expected behaviour) to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Mitch I added the Column result